# Opening up a Drop-Down-Menu Tkinter

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, tkinter

I have been implementing in a drop down menu (offically called a "`Tkinter.OptionMenu`") inside my application, that once clicked open will allow users to skip to certain parts of the form (like skipping to a certain chapter of a book/play). I want to be able to OPEN that drop down menu on an event i.e with code however as much as i have searched, it seems the very best i can do i to do a `.focus_set()` which is better than nothing, but all it does it place a faint outline around the widget. I would like it to fully open it up, just as if the user had clicked on it.

I'm pretty sure that i'm missing something simple, but help would be appreciated :)

Edit: Yes, i do have good reason to programatically open it, and even if i didn't it would still be nice to find out. I do not need access to the functions the list gives, but rather, i need the user to pick something from that drop down, and so i would like to open it for them

Comment: Why do you need to programatically open the menu? Is that what you _really_ need to do, or do you just need to trigger the function associated with picking an item?

Comment: no, i want the user to see that it is open (and save them a click) when they click up on a "menu" item (the ones at the top of an application). Currently it just focuses on it, but i want the user to be able to see more evidently thats its open ie to not miss it, but also to not have to have them open it up themselves. The user will then choose an option from inside the listed options